# Tomcat 6 and SSL not working

Tags: security, tomcat, ssl, https, tomcat6

I read a lot of tutorials about how to configure tomcat to work with ssl.

I access my application in **http://localhost:8080** and in **http://localhost:8443**, but I can´t access in **https://localhost:8443.**

I used the apache [HOWTO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

The file key.keystore work, because it´s used in other application with Jboss.

Bellow, it´s the new connector, in server.xml configuration.

```
<Connector 
    port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
    acceptCount="100" 
    SSLEnable="true" scheme="https" secure="true" 
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
    keystoreFile="C:/ambiente/server/tomcat/Tomcat6.0/conf/key.keystore" keystorePass="xxxx" />
```

What´s the problem?

Thanks for help.

Comment: SSLEnable looks wrong. Check it. If you can access http://host:8443 it is plaintext, not SSL. Question is off topic for SO, belongs on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with 
**SSLEnabled**="true" scheme="https" secure="true"